# Show outdated nuget packages with dotnet CLI

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I'm using .NET Core, VS Code, Linux.

To update a package, I manually change the version in the `.csproj` and then run `dotnet restore`.

But how can I tell which packages are outdated using the `dotnet` CLI?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Without installing any additional tool, I used this command:

```
dotnet list package --outdated
```

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/dotnet-list-package

Comment: And if it doesn't display newest version, for example released minutes ago, use "dotnet nuget locals --clear all"  command to clear Nuget cache before running list package command.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's anything within vanilla .NET Core, but I've found a .NET Core global tool called [NuKeeper](https://github.com/NuKeeperDotNet/NuKeeper/wiki/Getting-Started) which will do what you want:

```
# Install the global tool
$ dotnet tool install --global NuKeeper

# Run the tool to inspect a project in the current directory for updated dependencies
$ NuKeeper inspect
```

It can also perform the updates for you - see the link above for examples etc.

(I haven't used this before today, but I've just tried it on a sample project and it gave me the information I expected.)

Answer (score 2):

There is also the `dotnet outdated` global tool you can use.

https://github.com/jerriep/dotnet-outdated

```
dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated
dotnet outdated
```

Comment: This package has been deprecated. I would suggest using the [answer provided by Stephen Pham](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53700148/155899) as it is built in.

Comment: dotnet-outdated now lives here https://github.com/dotnet-outdated/dotnet-outdated. And can be installed by running `dotnet tool install --global dotnet-outdated-tool`.